# Documents in recent screens

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Android-L states that you can see the recent documents when the task button is pressed.

I have an app that opens a specific type of document where I just added the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT when launching my document activity. As expected, it shows a different document than the app itself in the task manager.

When I go back to the document list and try to open a new one, it keeps open the previously document. The documentation mentions getAppTasks() inside the class ActivityManager to get information about the task but not much more.

I guess I will have to have a way in my "document Activity" to know which document was selected in the task list. But no idea how.

Any hint on how to be able to switch between documents?

Comment: What do you mean by _method doesn't appear in the API_ ?

Comment: The docs mentions getAppTasks as an static method, just realized the class has to be instantiated. Im editing the question.